# DropDownList with Firefox and ASP.NET MVC

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, firefox

I have been hitting a brick wall on this for about an hour now.  I have a list of counties that I build and add to my view data (counties) and then render the list with a: `html.DropDownList('invoice.county', counties)` in my view.

It appears to render correctly but FF **REFUSES** to set the selected item.  I have tried swapping the values out for integers (so they don't match the display text) and that did not work.  FF just displays the first item in the list

```
<select id="invoice_county" name="invoice.county">
   ...
   <option value="Lander">Lander</option>
   <option selected="selected" value="Laramie">Laramie</option>
   <option value="Larimer">Larimer</option>
   ...
</select>
```

I have trimmed the values to the ones surrounding the selected item.

Can anyone give me insight into this????

Comment: What version of Firefox?  It seems to work fine for me in 3.0.7.  Also, could there be some script on the page that messing it up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using XHTML, you need a valid attribute/value pair:

```
<option selected="selected" value="x">
```

If you are using HTML, the mere presence of the attribute is enough:

```
<option selected value="x">
```

[More information on W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#edef-OPTION).

Answer (score 7):

Firefox has a weird bug/feature that means if you just refresh the page, it will select the option already selected regardless of whether the selected attribute is on another option. For example, if I put in:

```
<select id="invoice_county" name="invoice.county">
   <option value="Lander">Lander</option>
   <option selected="selected" value="Laramie">Laramie</option>
   <option value="Larimer">Larimer</option>
</select>
```

Saved and refreshed in Firefox, then put:

```
<select id="invoice_county" name="invoice.county">
   <option selected="selected" value="Lander">Lander</option>
   <option value="Laramie">Laramie</option>
   <option value="Larimer">Larimer</option>
</select>
```

instead and just refreshed after saving, it would keep "Laramie" selected. To stop this, try Ctrl-F5 rather than just F5 or refresh.

Comment: You can also use autocomplete=off to avoid telling users to do a Ctrl-F5.